# Interact with a background service?

Tags: php

What is the best way to interact with a background service? I have a C# program that run in the background to handle sending api requests to an external server. I want php to be able to queue up api requests to the service and get the responses. So here are my 2 ideas. Which would be better or is there a better way?

C# service runs a mini http server to accept api requests. The php script sends api requests to the service instead of the api. The service completes the request and adds the response to the database. Php script checks the status of the api response (triggered by an ajax request) in the database.

Or

C# service polls a queue table for api requests. Php script adds a request row to the queue. When the service finds rows, it completes the request and either adds the response to a response table or updates the queue row. Php script checks the status of the api response (triggered by an ajax request) in the database.

The second idea seems easier to execute but I imagine constantly polling a database (MYSQL) might not be a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [message queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue), such as [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/).

Comment: That's essentially what I mean with the first idea.

Comment: Right. But now you don't have to build it yourself.

Comment: Honestly for the scale I am working with its probably easier/faster to just build it myself.